# SQL - how to get previous value and nexrt vale in rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
create table office(rec_id varchar(10),curr_off varchar(10),orderflag int);


insert into office values
('A1','A11',1),
('A1','A12',2),
('A1','A13',3),
('A1','A14',4),
('B1','B11',1),
('B1','B12',2),
('B1','B13',3),
('B1','B14',4),
('C1','C11',1),
('C1','C12',2),
('C1','C13',3),
('C1','C14',4);
```

union query

```
SELECT REC_ID,CURR_OFF,ORDERFLAG
FROM OFFICE a1 where rec_id = ‘A1’
union
SELECT REC_ID,CURR_OFF,ORDERFLAG
FROM OFFICE a1 where rec_id = ‘B1’
Union
SELECT REC_ID,CURR_OFF,ORDERFLAG
FROM OFFICE a1 where rec_id = ‘C1’
ORDER BY REC_ID,ORDERFLAG DESC;
```

expected result

```
Rec_id  Curr_off    Order_flag  Pre_off Next_off
  A1      A14            4         A13     null
  A1      A13            3         A12     A14
  A1      A12            2         A11     A13
  A1      A11            1         null    A12
  B1      B14            4         B13     null
  B2      B13            3         B12     B14
  B3      B12            2         B11     B13
  B4      B11            1         null    B12
  C1      C14            4         C13     null
  C2      C13            3         C12     C14
  C3      C12            2         C11     C13
  C4      C11            1         null    C12
```

how can i get the result set like this, this is dummy data where i have to apply logic for more union quieris and i can not extend unions and reduce also.

Comment: Rows in a database have no intrinsic order, however you could add a column containing a row number. To find the next row you simply look for the row with the number `number+1`, and the previous row would have row number `number-1`. Using an auto-incrementing column, for the row number column, is probably the way to go.

Comment: Do you have a way of identifying the order the data is in such as an auto_increment id field or a date   - if not then there is nothing you can do with the data.

Comment: what is i add a column in every union like '1 as sno' '2 as sno', will this be helpful?

Comment: What does orderflag denote?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming orderflag has some meaning you could do this

```
select rec_id,curr_off, orderflag, 
(select curr_off from t t1 where t1.rec_id = t.rec_id and t1.orderflag < t.orderflag order  by orderflag desc limit 1) prev,
(select curr_off from t t1 where t1.rec_id = t.rec_id and t1.orderflag > t.orderflag order  by orderflag asc limit 1) next
from t
order by rec_id,orderflag desc
;
```

which uses a limit clause with a sort in the sub query 
or this which uses a self join

```
select t.rec_id,t.curr_off, t.orderflag, tprev.curr_off prev, tnext.curr_off next
from t
left join t tprev on tprev.rec_id = t.rec_id and tprev.orderflag = t.orderflag - 1
left join t tnext on tnext.rec_id = t.rec_id and tnext.orderflag = t.orderflag + 1
order by t.rec_id, t.orderflag desc 
;

 +--------+----------+-----------+------+------+
| rec_id | curr_off | orderflag | prev | next |
+--------+----------+-----------+------+------+
| A1     | A14      |         4 | A13  | NULL |
| A1     | A13      |         3 | A12  | A14  |
| A1     | A12      |         2 | A11  | A13  |
| A1     | A11      |         1 | NULL | A12  |
| B1     | B14      |         4 | B13  | NULL |
| B1     | B13      |         3 | B12  | B14  |
| B1     | B12      |         2 | B11  | B13  |
| B1     | B11      |         1 | NULL | B12  |
| C1     | C14      |         4 | C13  | NULL |
| C1     | C13      |         3 | C12  | C14  |
| C1     | C12      |         2 | C11  | C13  |
| C1     | C11      |         1 | NULL | C12  |
+--------+----------+-----------+------+------+
12 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you, i got the idea and modified the logic which is needed.